# Prettier does not format .vue files consistenly

Tags: vue.js, prettier, vue-i18n

Does somebody have an idea why does Prettier sometimes separates attributes like this:

```
:label="
                                        $t(
                                            'watercourseStructureProtocol.generalWaterbodyInfo.waterbodySamplingLocation'
                                        )
                                    "
```

And in some others like this? (This how I want it to be)

```
:label="$t('watercourseStructureProtocol.generalWaterbodyInfo.ecoregion')"
```

This happens exclusively when using i18n syntax.

I already tried incrementing printWidth with no results.

My default editor for .vue files is "esbenp.prettier-vscode".

Thanks

Comment: I doubt this is specific to i18n. Try another function call of the same length in a template. And I doubt this can be affected a lot, Prettier is not configurable, it works like it works. The whole code wasn't shown, maybe try to wrap the whole attribute on a new line in case you didn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.